# Weird "basename" behavior

Tags: bash

Why do:

```bash
find ../ -type f | xargs -Ifilename echo "$(basename filename)"
```

and

```bash
find ../ -type f | xargs -Ifilename basename "$(echo filename)"
```

give different outputs? This can be run on any directory.

Comment: The important thing to understand here is that the command substitution (`$(...)`) happens **before** `xargs` is even started.

Comment: why `basename "$(echo filename)"` instead of just `basename "filename"`? Similarly `echo "$(basename filename)"` is redundant. Never use echo just to reprint an output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Running the commands under `set -x` can tell you:

```bash
set -x
diff <(find ../ -type f | xargs -If1 echo "$(basename f1)") <(find ../ -type f | xargs -If2 basename "$(echo f2)")
```

```
++ find ../ -type f
+ diff /dev/fd/63 /dev/fd/62
+++ basename f1
++ find ../ -type f
+++ echo f2
++ xargs -If2 basename f2
++ xargs -If1 echo f1
```

You can se "echo f1". So, in the `xargs -If1 echo "$(basename f1)"` case, the `$(...)` was run **before** xargs (because command substitution happens before running the command). The result of `basename f1` was `f1`, which was sent as the argument to `xargs`, so it printed the paths.